# How to automatically Update place linked file without switching to photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I know How to update "place linked..." file in Photoshop CC.

I have placed illustrator file as a place linked file in Photoshop. "Place Linked" automatically updates when i save illustrator file but i need to switch to Photoshop to view the updated file.

Can Photoshop update the place linked file automatically without switching to Photoshop?  . PS: Photoshop is opened in the background.

[image: Switch back to photoshop to see the changes]

Comment: Welcome to GD.SE. May I ask what does inDesign have to do with your question (since you added the tag)?

Comment: If you are not using PS why should it update the file? For what the programs know you are still using illustrator so there is no reason for it to fetch data from the file?

Comment: @Luciano i want to work on PS, AI and INDD simultaneously.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I am using AI in my workflow  to use vector objects in My PS file. Am on Dual screen monitor setup want to preview changes live without switching to PS.

Comment: @Sachin fine, but INDD has nothing to do with the question

Comment: @Luciano I have removed the tag can you help with this question ?

Comment: Yeah, you use two monitors but for Ps and Ai it means nothing. As long as you use others programs (in your case illustrator) it have no sense to update the view in Ps. It would slow down the programs and take on RAM. I get the idea behind your will but it's just waste of resources.

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY I don't Have issue with resource. I have 16gb RAM i7 processor and SSD drive. It runs program smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, no. The other program will not check for updates (and therefore will not update) until it is moved to the foreground.

You can rapidly switch back and forth by using alt+tab twice (cmd+tab on Mac) as a fast way to see the changes without having to use the mouse.